# Stream screen react native using MediaRecorder

Tags: java, android, react-native

I can not find any package to stream what the user is doing out of the application with react native.

I am creating my own plugin

The goal is to send a stream from java to javascript to then send it an external socket server via socket.io

This is my java class to ask authorization and stream

```
import android.hardware.display.DisplayManager;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.projection.MediaProjectionManager;
import android.media.projection.MediaProjection;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.util.Log;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Promise;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ActivityEventListener;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.BaseActivityEventListener;

import static android.content.Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE;

public class ScreenMirroringModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {

    private static final int SCREEN_SHARE_REQUEST = 4242;
    private static final String S_MIRROR_CANCELLED = "S_MIRROR_CANCELLED";


    private Promise sMirrorPromise;
    private MediaProjectionManager mMediaProjectionManager;
    private MediaStreamer mMediaStreamer = new MediaStreamer();

    private final ActivityEventListener mActivityEventListener = new BaseActivityEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(Activity activity, int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
            if (requestCode == SCREEN_SHARE_REQUEST) {
                if (sMirrorPromise != null) {
                    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                        sMirrorPromise.reject(S_MIRROR_CANCELLED, "Screen mirroring was cancelled");
                    } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
                        activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

                        mMediaStreamer.reset();

                        mMediaStreamer.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
                        mMediaStreamer.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
                        mMediaStreamer.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);
                        mMediaStreamer.setVideoSize(dm.widthPixels, dm.heightPixels);
                        mMediaStreamer.setVideoFrameRate(30);

                        StreamTask st =  new StreamTask();
                        st.execute(mMediaStreamer);
                        try {
                            st.get();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            sMirrorPromise.reject(e);
                        }

                        MediaProjection mMediaProjection = mMediaProjectionManager.getMediaProjection(resultCode, intent);

                        try {
                            mMediaProjection.createVirtualDisplay("MainActivity",
                                    dm.widthPixels, dm.heightPixels, dm.densityDpi,
                                    DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_AUTO_MIRROR,
                                    mMediaStreamer.getSurface(), null /*Callbacks*/, null/*Handler*/);
                            mMediaStreamer.start();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            //Log.v("ReactNative", Log.getStackTraceString(e));
                            sMirrorPromise.reject(e);
                        }

                        sMirrorPromise.resolve("Test");

                    }

                }
                sMirrorPromise = null;
            }
        }
    };

    public ScreenMirroringModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);

        // Add the listener for `onActivityResult`
        reactContext.addActivityEventListener(mActivityEventListener);
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "ScreenMirroring";
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void stream(String ip, int port, Promise promise) {
        final Activity activity = getCurrentActivity();

        // Store the promise to resolve/reject when picker returns data
        sMirrorPromise = promise;

        mMediaProjectionManager = (MediaProjectionManager) activity.getSystemService(MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = mMediaProjectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent();
        activity.startActivityForResult(intent, SCREEN_SHARE_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

This is my class which is transforming the recording into a stream

```
package com.ijkoareactapp;

import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.net.LocalServerSocket;
import android.net.LocalSocket;
import android.net.LocalSocketAddress;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class MediaStreamer extends MediaRecorder {
    private LocalServerSocket localServerSocket = null;
    private LocalSocket receiver, sender = null;

    public void prepare() throws IllegalStateException, IOException {

        receiver = new LocalSocket();
        try {
            localServerSocket = new LocalServerSocket("screen_mirror_socket");
            receiver.connect(new LocalSocketAddress("screen_mirror_socket"));
            receiver.setReceiveBufferSize(4096);
            receiver.setSendBufferSize(4096);
            sender = localServerSocket.accept();
            sender.setReceiveBufferSize(4096);
            sender.setSendBufferSize(4096);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IOException("Can't create local socket !");
        }


        setOutputFile(sender.getFileDescriptor());

        try {
            super.prepare();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v("ReactNative", Log.getStackTraceString(e));

            closeSockets();
            throw e;
        }
    }

    public InputStream getInputStream() {

        InputStream out = null;

        try {
            out = receiver.getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        return out;

    }


    public void stop() {
        closeSockets();
        super.stop();
    }

    private void closeSockets() {
        if (localServerSocket != null) {
            try {
                localServerSocket.close();
                sender.close();
                receiver.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {

            }
            localServerSocket = null;
            sender = null;
            receiver = null;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the class which is running the task in background because I can not start a local socket in main process

```
package com.ijkoareactapp;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

public class StreamTask extends AsyncTask <MediaStreamer, Integer, Long>{

    protected Long doInBackground(MediaStreamer... mediaStreamers) {

        Log.v("ReactNative", "Start");

        for(int i = 0; i < mediaStreamers.length; i++) {
            try {
                mediaStreamers[i].prepare();
                Log.v("ReactNative", "Prepared");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.v("ReactNative", "Error");
                Log.v("ReactNative", Log.getStackTraceString(e));
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

The error I have is

```
08-05 15:28:49.465   555   571 V ReactNative: java.lang.IllegalStateException
08-05 15:28:49.465   555   571 V ReactNative:   at android.media.MediaRecorder._prepare(Native Method)
08-05 15:28:49.465   555   571 V ReactNative:   at android.media.MediaRecorder.prepare(MediaRecorder.java:827)
08-05 15:28:49.465   555   571 V ReactNative:   at com.ijkoareactapp.MediaStreamer.prepare(MediaStreamer.java:37)
08-05 15:28:49.465   555   571 V ReactNative:   at com.ijkoareactapp.StreamTask.doInBackground(StreamTask.java:14)
08-05 15:28:49.465   555   571 V ReactNative:   at com.ijkoareactapp.StreamTask.doInBackground(StreamTask.java:6)
08-05 15:28:49.465   555   571 V ReactNative:   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
08-05 15:28:49.465   555   571 V ReactNative:   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
08-05 15:28:49.465   555   571 V ReactNative:   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
08-05 15:28:49.465   555   571 V ReactNative:   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
08-05 15:28:49.465   555   571 V ReactNative:   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
08-05 15:28:49.465   555   571 V ReactNative:   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Reading some documentation it seems that `prepare` is called before `start` or after `setOutputFormat` but this is not the case.

I think that my internal socket connection is not well initialized but I can not find the right way to do it.

As well not sure where should I put the `mMediaProjection.createVirtualDisplay`, at the moment I have the follwing error should be because the `prepare does not works`

```
08-05 15:43:36.077  1575  1575 V ReactNative: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to get surface
08-05 15:43:36.077  1575  1575 V ReactNative:   at android.media.MediaRecorder.getSurface(Native Method)
08-05 15:43:36.077  1575  1575 V ReactNative:   at com.ijkoareactapp.ScreenMirroringModule$1.onActivityResult(ScreenMirroringModule.java:65)
08-05 15:43:36.077  1575  1575 V ReactNative:   at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext.onActivityResult(ReactContext.java:262)
08-05 15:43:36.077  1575  1575 V ReactNative:   at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.onActivityResult(ReactInstanceManager.java:703)
08-05 15:43:36.077  1575  1575 V ReactNative:   at com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate.onActivityResult(ReactActivityDelegate.java:124)
08-05 15:43:36.077  1575  1575 V ReactNative:   at com.facebook.react.ReactActivity.onActivityResult(ReactActivity.java:75)
08-05 15:43:36.077  1575  1575 V ReactNative:   at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6915)
08-05 15:43:36.077  1575  1575 V ReactNative:   at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4049)
08-05 15:43:36.077  1575  1575 V ReactNative:   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4096)
08-05 15:43:36.077  1575  1575 V ReactNative:   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java)
08-05 15:43:36.077  1575  1575 V ReactNative:   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1516)
08-05 15:43:36.077  1575  1575 V ReactNative:   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-05 15:43:36.077  1575  1575 V ReactNative:   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
08-05 15:43:36.077  1575  1575 V ReactNative:   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
08-05 15:43:36.077  1575  1575 V ReactNative:   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-05 15:43:36.077  1575  1575 V ReactNative:   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
08-05 15:43:36.077  1575  1575 V ReactNative:   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

Answer (score 0):

it's hard to reproduce your problem locally.
You may be right with wrong order of MediaStreamer initialisation.
Try to follow this sequence line by line:

1. setVideoSource
2. setOutputFormat
3. setVideoEncoder
4. setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface())
5. setOutputFile
6. prepare
7. start

If it doesn't help, the best suggestion I have - take a look to working React Native/Android project and try to find the difference:
https://github.com/ycswaves/react-native-screen-recorder/blob/master/android/app/src/main/java/com/screenrecorder/MainActivity.java#L131~L143
or this:
https://github.com/fyhertz/spydroid-ipcamera/blob/779f1035ac8fd91be5dfba99516da1b9f29f8768/src/net/majorkernelpanic/streaming/video/VideoStream.java#L339~L357

According to this repos OutputFormat.MPEG_4 isn't the best choose with sockets. Would you like to try THREE_GPP?

And the last thing, you have to add additional permissions for your app:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answers but I do not understand why I have to use those permissions, and why should I call `setPreviewDisplay` ?
I tried both and still not working

Comment: As I can understand, MediaRecorder is trying to save recorded video to output file what could require adding android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE to AndroidManifest.xml. Could you share more source code somehow so I could apply this configuration https://github.com/ycswaves/react-native-screen-recorder/blob/master/android/app/src/main/java/com/screenrecorder/MainActivity.java and try to build/run it by myself?

Answer (score 0):

May I correct your `ScreenMirroringModule` and `StreamTask` to solve the issue,

`StreamTask`

```java
package com.ijkoareactapp;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

public class StreamTask extends AsyncTask <MediaStreamer, Integer, Long>{
    private StreamTaskStatus streamTaskStatus;

    public StreamTask(StreamTaskStatus streamTaskStatus) {
          this.streamTaskStatus = streamTaskStatus;
    }

    protected Long doInBackground(MediaStreamer... mediaStreamers) {

        Log.v("ReactNative", "Start");

        for(int i = 0; i < mediaStreamers.length; i++) {
            try {
                mediaStreamers[i].prepare();
                Log.v("ReactNative", "Prepared");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.v("ReactNative", "Error");
                Log.v("ReactNative", Log.getStackTraceString(e));
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    public onPostExecute() {
        if (this.streamTaskStatus != null) {
             this.streamTaskStatus.streamTaskCompleted();
        }
    }

    public interface StreamTaskStatus {
       void streamTaskCompleted();
    }
}
```

`ScreenMirroringModule`

```java
import android.hardware.display.DisplayManager;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.projection.MediaProjectionManager;
import android.media.projection.MediaProjection;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.util.Log;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Promise;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ActivityEventListener;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.BaseActivityEventListener;

import static android.content.Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE;

public class ScreenMirroringModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule, implements StreamTaskStatus {

    private static final int SCREEN_SHARE_REQUEST = 4242;
    private static final String S_MIRROR_CANCELLED = "S_MIRROR_CANCELLED";


    private Promise sMirrorPromise;
    private StreamTask st;
    private MediaProjectionManager mMediaProjectionManager;
    private MediaStreamer mMediaStreamer = new MediaStreamer();

    private final ActivityEventListener mActivityEventListener = new BaseActivityEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(Activity activity, int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
            if (requestCode == SCREEN_SHARE_REQUEST) {
                if (sMirrorPromise != null) {
                    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                        sMirrorPromise.reject(S_MIRROR_CANCELLED, "Screen mirroring was cancelled");
                    } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
                        activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

                        mMediaStreamer.reset();

                        mMediaStreamer.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
                        mMediaStreamer.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
                        mMediaStreamer.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);
                        mMediaStreamer.setVideoSize(dm.widthPixels, dm.heightPixels);
                        mMediaStreamer.setVideoFrameRate(30);

                        st =  new StreamTask(ScreenMirroringModule.this);
                        st.execute(mMediaStreamer);


                    }

                }
                sMirrorPromise = null;
            }
        }
    };

    public ScreenMirroringModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);

        // Add the listener for `onActivityResult`
        reactContext.addActivityEventListener(mActivityEventListener);
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "ScreenMirroring";
    }

    @Override
    public void streamTaskCompleted() {
 MediaProjection mMediaProjection = mMediaProjectionManager.getMediaProjection(resultCode, intent);


                        try {
                            mMediaProjection.createVirtualDisplay("MainActivity",
                                    dm.widthPixels, dm.heightPixels, dm.densityDpi,
                                    DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_AUTO_MIRROR,
                                    mMediaStreamer.getSurface(), null /*Callbacks*/, null/*Handler*/);
                            mMediaStreamer.start();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            //Log.v("ReactNative", Log.getStackTraceString(e));
                            sMirrorPromise.reject(e);
                        }

                        sMirrorPromise.resolve("Test");
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void stream(String ip, int port, Promise promise) {
        final Activity activity = getCurrentActivity();

        // Store the promise to resolve/reject when picker returns data
        sMirrorPromise = promise;

        mMediaProjectionManager = (MediaProjectionManager) activity.getSystemService(MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = mMediaProjectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent();
        activity.startActivityForResult(intent, SCREEN_SHARE_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

**Explanation**
The operation you were performing was async (using Async task) and we are waiting in the main thread again, this might have caused the `IllegalStateException`.

Please check if this helps, as I do not have Android studios setup I cannot validate.

Lemme know if there is any other issue I will try to help

**Update**

One more missing thing might be the following steps, which I found in this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#capture-video),

**Start Recording Video** - The following steps must be completed in order to successfully record video:

- **Unlock the Camera** - Unlock the camera for use by MediaRecorder by calling Camera.unlock().
- **Configure MediaRecorder** - Call in the following MediaRecorder methods in this order. For more information, see the MediaRecorder reference documentation.

  - **setCamera()** - Set the camera to be used for video capture, use your application's current instance of Camera.
  - **setAudioSource()** - Set the audio source, use MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER.
  - **setVideoSource()** - Set the video source, use MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA.
  - Set the video output format and encoding. For Android 2.2 (API Level 8) and higher, use the MediaRecorder.setProfile method, and get a profile instance using CamcorderProfile.get(). For versions of Android prior to 2.2, you must set the video output format and encoding parameters:

    - **setOutputFormat()** - Set the output format, specify the default setting or MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4.
    - **setAudioEncoder()** - Set the sound encoding type, specify the default setting or MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB.
    - **setVideoEncoder()** - Set the video encoding type, specify the default setting or MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP.
  - **setOutputFile()** - Set the output file, use getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO).toString() from the example method in the Saving Media Files section.
  - **setPreviewDisplay()** - Specify the SurfaceView preview layout element for your application. Use the same object you specified for Connect
    Preview.

> Caution: You must call these MediaRecorder configuration methods in
>   this order, otherwise your application will encounter errors and the
>   recording will fail.

- **Prepare MediaRecorder** - Prepare the MediaRecorder with provided configuration settings by calling MediaRecorder.prepare().
- **Start MediaRecorder** - Start recording video by calling MediaRecorder.start().

**Please note the caution as it says we have to follow this order and the steps.**

Also give the respective camera permissions required.

Comment: Thanks for your message, I had exactly the same idea with, implemented it and I have the same issue.
I just implemented your code and I still have the same issue `java.lang.IllegalStateException at android.media.MediaRecorder._prepare(Native Method)` Can be due to `react native` which have issues with `MediaRecorder`

Comment: Same one than the first log in the main post

Comment: @Ajouve any reason you are extending MediaRecorder rather than using as a class object?

Comment: Yes to create a stream using LocalSocket

Comment: Updated answer, please check if it helps.. sorry m unable to test n tell you as unable to reproduce..

Comment: Just tried and have the same error, I am not using camera but streaming the screen